# NullPointerException when trying to access a Button of a ListView layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a MainActivity with an activity_main.xml layout. I have a custom ListView, which renders its own layout for each ListView item:

ItemAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Loop loop = getItem(position);

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
```

In that list_item.xml layout, I have an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
        android:id="@+id/overflowMenu"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

In the MainActivity's onCreate. I am trying to set an OnClickListener to that ImageButton:

```
    final ImageButton overflowMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.overflowMenu);
    overflowMenu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                    = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(overflowMenu, 50, -30);

        }}
    );
```

However, apparently on the MainActivity's onCreate that ListView layout is not generated yet, and therefore that ImageButton cannot be found, I guess? As a result, I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

So how am I supposed to set the OnClickListener on this ImageButton?

Comment: set onclicklistner in the getView method

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the OnClickListener of that ImageButton inside your getView() methord of Adapter.

You can use **View Inflator** for this

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // INFLATE A VIEW
    View v=View.inflate(context,layout,null);
    // GET BUTTON HANDLER
    ImageButton overflowMenu = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.overflowMenu);
    // HANDLE CLICK EVENT
    overflowMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // DO YOUR WORK HERE
        }
    });
    // RETURN THAT VIEW
    return v;
}
```

Hope it solves

Comment: What about getBaseContext?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
final ImageButton overflowMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.overflowMenu);
```

With this line

```
final ImageButton overflowMenu = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.overflowMenu);
```

Comment: What about getBaseContext?

Comment: //intitialize this;
    Context activity_context;
    LayoutInflater   inflater;
    //make a constructor 
    public ItemAdapter(Context con)
    {
        activity_context = con;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    //inflate this in getView
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);